# Sidebar height varies with content length

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am having a problem with the length of my sidebar in my angular2 app. I have a navigation component which includes both top navigation html and sidebar navigation html. When the app loads the sidebar is fine. If i route to other components the sidebar becomes short or long depending on that component length. I want to fix the height of sidebar. Please see images to understand what i am trying to say. The theme template was taken from [here](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview).

Fig 1 - When the app loads
[image: When the app loads]

Fig 2- When navigate to other component
[image: Navigated to other component]

Fig 3 - It becomes more short
[image: Becomes more short]

**loggedIn.component.html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <bmis-navigation></bmis-navigation>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**navigation.component.html**

The html is [here](http://pastebin.com/GYanzzGa)
The css files are linked below.
1- [Admin.css](http://pastebin.com/dZQ9JBnB)
2- [red.css](http://pastebin.com/dGs0kD4p)

Comment: Can you send us your css/less files ?

Comment: I have linked the css files. I am not using less

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS, so it's hard to diagnose this problem. That being said, based on the code provided I would guess your problem lies in there, more than the DOM itself.

Have you given setting a `min-height` on the `main-sidebar` class, or a similar solution? I would suggest, depending on your needs, something along these lines:

```
.main-sidebar {
  min-height: ~"calc(100vh - @navigation-height)";
}
```

Again, there isn't much context as far as the styling, but I hope this helps!

P.S. I apologize if my LESS syntax is off at all, I believe you're using it, but I'm out of practice.

Comment: I have linked the css files. I am not using less.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Angular or what you are using.

But I think setting a min-height for your sidebar would solve the issue.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer